# Front custom edit post page for each post

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I have made a custom post type named `ticket` and I want to make an edit page for every single ticket like StackOverflow if the question is like this:

wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109592/how-can-do-this/

The edit page of this question will be:

wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109592/how-can-do-this/edit

and make a custom template PHP file for the content of this page.

How can achive this please?

Comment: There's probably a lot of different ways to do this but you're going to have to start somewhere; what I'd do is make a slight change and use a query string like `wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109592/how-can-do-this/?john_edit=1` or `wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109592/how-can-do-this/?john_edit=true` then in the template for the CPT I'd run a quick check at the top to see if `john_edit` is set (using `isset()`) and then change what's being displayed in the template based on that.  False is the ticket content, true would be a form to edit the ticket.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yes, I have thought about this solution but it's not professional! Also what about the title of the page? We need to modify it to be like "Edit Ticket - The title of ticket"

Comment: Sorry, how is a query string “not professional”?  And editing the page title to prepend it with “Edit -“ is simple once you have the conditional check working.